# How to verify Appian license files on Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, license-key, appian

We are running an experimental Appian (platform) on Kubernetes and now it is time for a scheduled replacement of the license files. Appian licenses come in pairs, namely `K3.lic` and `K4.lic` and are binary. For a usual (non-Kubernetes) Appian on-premise installation, we can use the Appian tools `./k` and `QHOME=.. ./q` respectively to display additional the details of those files, e.g. how long the licenses are valid.

**Is there a way to check license details within the Appian license files up-front, without stopping and restarting the Appian on Kubernetes?**

*What I tried so far:* I looked for information about the licenses within the log files by

```
k logs -k "app.kubernetes.io/name=appian" --tail=-1 | grep -i License
```

but it looks like I might only receive messages in case of an error.

#### Background

I am asking here on StackOverflow since I am hoping for some help from the Kubernetes specialists out there. As far as I can tell, Appian's Kubernetes architecture seems to mimic the VM-architecture from the standard on-premise installation, and my colleague was able to see the respective folder structure within a pod, but we were not able to execute the `./k` script.

#### References

- In the Appian Community, there is a question by Carlos Santander *[Appian Permanent License (K3.lic and K4.lic) to run Appian in docker](https://community.appian.com/discussions/f/administration/20481/appian-permanent-license-k3-lic-and-k4-lic-to-run-appian-in-docker)* from 2020 which did not answer my question.
- There is also a rather historic support case *[KB-1033 "k3.lic" error when running engine scripts](https://community.appian.com/support/w/kb/258/kb-1033-k3-lic-error-when-running-engine-scripts)* which mentions the `com.appian.komodo.engine.KLicenseVerifier` which I did not see in the Kubernetes logs.

Comment: Why exactly was my question marked as "not about programming or software development"? Appian is indeed a software developing platform and I intentionally asked here and not in the close-community of the company since I am hoping for some help from the Kubernetes specialists here on SO.